# D3: Trouble updating selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having issues with my `update()` function. Here, within `svg.append('rect')` I have `.on('click')` where I simply change the data, then run `update()`.

Why doesn't this work? How do I make it work?

```
  var width = 640,
      height = 480;

  var graphNodes = [
    { id: 0, x: 39, y: 343, r: 15 },
    { id: 1, x: 425, y: 38, r: 15 },
    { id: 2, x: 183, y: 417, r: 15 },
    { id: 3, x: 564, y: 31, r: 15 },
    { id: 4, x: 553, y: 351, r: 15 },
    { id: 5, x: 454, y: 298, r: 15 },
    { id: 6, x: 493, y: 123, r: 15 },
    { id: 7, x: 471, y: 427, r: 15 },
    { id: 8, x: 142, y: 154, r: 15 }
  ];

  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

  svg.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'graph')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'lightblue')
      .attr('opacity', 0.3)
      .on('click', function(){

        graphNodes[8].id = 'hey there'; //  <----- Why doesn't this happen?

        update();
      });

  var nodeGroup = svg.selectAll('.nodes')
      .data(graphNodes, function(d){ return d.id; })
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node');

  nodeGroup.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y })
      .attr("r", function(d){ return d.r; })
      .attr("fill", "gray");

  nodeGroup.append('text')
      .attr("dx", function(d){ return d.x + 20; })
      .attr("dy", function(d){ return d.y + 5; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.id });

  function update() {

    if(nodeGroup){

      // Update nodes
      var node = nodeGroup.data(graphNodes, function(d){ return d.id; }),
          nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
              .attr('class', 'node');

      nodeEnter.append('circle')
              .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
              .attr('r', function(d){ return d.r; })
              .attr('fill', 'gray');

      nodeEnter.append('text')
          .attr("dx", function(d){ return d.x + 20; })
          .attr("dy", function(d){ return d.y + 5; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.id });

      nodeGroup = nodeEnter.merge(node);
      node.exit().remove();
    }
  }
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g74p0z5v/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typed this as a comment in the message you left me, but here it is as an answer.

You need to separate out the things you do on enter, on update and on exit. On enter you want to just append and set any attributes that never change. On update you want to add/change the text and add/change the radius. On exit you remove. Here I've properly handled the enter, update, exit paradigm:

```
  // bind the data
  var node = nodeGroup.data(graphNodes, function(d){ return d.id; }),
      // this is the enter selection
      nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
          .attr('class', 'node');

  // append to enter selection
  // append and set color, we never change color
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
          .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
          .attr('fill', 'gray');

  // again entering, append text and set position
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dx", function(d){ return d.x + 20; })
      .attr("dy", function(d){ return d.y + 5; });          

  // nodeGroup is the enter + update selection
  nodeGroup = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // change the things we want to change on every update
  nodeGroup.select("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.text ? d.text : d.id });

  nodeGroup.select("circle")
   .attr('r', function(d){ return d.r; })

  // exit, just remove
  node.exit().remove();
```

---

Running code:

```js
var width = 640,
      height = 480;

  var graphNodes = [
    { id: 0, x: 39, y: 343, r: 15 },
    { id: 1, x: 425, y: 38, r: 15 },
    { id: 2, x: 183, y: 417, r: 15 },
    { id: 3, x: 564, y: 31, r: 15 },
    { id: 4, x: 553, y: 351, r: 15 },
    { id: 5, x: 454, y: 298, r: 15 },
    { id: 6, x: 493, y: 123, r: 15 },
    { id: 7, x: 471, y: 427, r: 15 },
    { id: 8, x: 142, y: 154, r: 15 }
  ];

  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

  svg.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'graph')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'lightblue')
      .attr('opacity', 0.3)
      .on('click', function(){
        /*graphNodes.push({
          x: d3.mouse(this)[0],
          y: d3.mouse(this)[1],
          id: graphNodes.length,
          r: 15
        });*/

        graphNodes.splice(2, 1);
        
        graphNodes[Math.floor(Math.random() * graphNodes.length)].text = "Tomato!";
        
        graphNodes[Math.floor(Math.random() * graphNodes.length)].r = Math.random() * 30;
        
        update();
      });

  var nodeGroup = svg.selectAll('.nodes')
      .data(graphNodes, function(d){ return d.id; })
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node');

  nodeGroup.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y })
      .attr("r", function(d){ return d.r; })
      .attr("fill", "gray");

  nodeGroup.append('text')
      .attr("dx", function(d){ return d.x + 20; })
      .attr("dy", function(d){ return d.y + 5; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.id });

  function update() {
  
    if(nodeGroup){

      // Update nodes
      var node = nodeGroup.data(graphNodes, function(d){ return d.id; }),
          nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
              .attr('class', 'node');
      
      // this is the enter selection
      // append and set color, we never change color
      nodeEnter.append('circle')
              .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
              .attr('fill', 'gray');

      nodeEnter.append('text')
          .attr("dx", function(d){ return d.x + 20; })
          .attr("dy", function(d){ return d.y + 5; });          

      // nodeGroup is the enter + update selection
      nodeGroup = nodeEnter.merge(node);
      
      // change the things we want to change on every update
      nodeGroup.select("text")
       .text(function(d) { return d.text ? d.text : d.id });
        
      nodeGroup.select("circle")
       .attr('r', function(d){ return d.r; })
      
      // exit, just remove
      node.exit().remove();
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```